# What's the difference between Cleaned data and is valid in django

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms, cleaned-data

What is the difference between cleaned_data and is_valid functions in django?, I just came across forms and immediately i got stuck there

can anyone play with some simple examples. I've read many documentation but i cant able to differentiate it.

Answer (score 2):

1. `is_valid()` method is used to perform validation for each field of the form.
2. `cleaned_data` is where all validated fields are stored.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. If possible can u give with some examples

Answer (score 0):

Cleaned data: Clean data are valid, accurate, complete, consistent, unique, and uniform. (Dirty data include inconsistencies and errors.)

Cleaned data valid in django: It uses uses a clean and easy approach to validate data. The is_valid() method is used to perform validation for each field of the form, it is defined in **Django** Form class. It returns True if data is valid and place all data into a cleaned_data attribute.

Answer (score 0):

## EXAMPLE

```
 def InsertData(request):
        form = Student()
        if request.method == 'POST':
            form = Student(request.POST,request.FILES)
            if form.is_valid():
                fname = form.cleaned_data['fname']
                lname = form.cleaned_data['lname']
                email = form.cleaned_data['email']
                password1 = form.cleaned_data['password1']
                password2 = form.cleaned_data['password2']
                if password1 == password2:
                    form.save()
                    messages.success(request,'Student Successfully Inserted')
                    return redirect('/home/')
                else:
                    messages.error(request,'Password does not match !')
                    return redirect('/home/')
        context= {'form':form,}
        return render(request,'home.html',context)
    
    
    ### If we have used clean data in password1 and password2, then we can give condition that password1 and password2 must be same and it's length must be bigger then 7 we can do with the help of clean data and is_valid() will check that data is valid or not if it is valid then it will save the data.
```